# C programming: Strings

Tags: c, string

My problem is: Input name and print out in the order

Ex: input the name : Martin Luther King

result : King,Martin-Luther

But when i run this code it prints out :  King,LutherMartin-Luther. Can you help show me the mistake?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
char name[100];
int i;
printf("input full name: "); gets(name);
char * c =&name[strlen(name)-1];
while (*(c)!=' ')
    c--;
printf("%s,",c);
*c= '\0';
char *d=&name;
while (*(d)!=' ')
    d++;
printf("%s",d);
*d='-';
printf("%s",name);
getch();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your first printf prints "King,", second printf prints "Luther". After that, you do not set `*d` to NULL, you set it to `'-'`. At that point, name becomes `"Martin-Luther\0King\0"`. So the last printf prints "Martin-Luther". So, your second printf is unnecessary if you're converting "X Y Z" to "Z,X-Y".

Comment: What happened to indentation and braces?

Comment: the header file conio.h is not portable.  suggest removing that header file and replacing getch() with getchar()

Comment: @user3629249 thank you :) i use both visual and code block, so when i use visual i have to use conio.h

Comment: for human readability, 1) after each opening brace '{' indent the code 4 spaces.  2) before each closing brace '}' un-indent the code.  3) insert a blank line before/after each while/if/else code block.  debug (and later maintenance) will be greatly eased by placing appropriate comments in the code

Comment: in C, the name of an array devolves to the address of the array.  So this line: 'char *d=&name;' should be: 'char *d=name;'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
printf("%s",d);
```

is the root of the problem as it results in the extra print of the middle name.  Simply remove that line.

Answer (score 0):

The string is "Martin Luther King"
You Display "King" first.
Then "Martin".
Then again "Martin-Luther".

Just remove the printf at line 17.